# On line integrals of $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2 +y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, stokes-theorem

There are a few questions on MSE about integrals of the form $$\int_C \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2 +y^2},$$ where $C$ is a smooth simple closed positively oriented curve; but none of them gave me a complete understanding of what's going on.

Basically, there are two cases depending on whether $C$ encloses the origin or not. Is there a general result saying that in the former case $C$ can be replaced with a homotopic closed curve and the value of the integral won't change (a particular case of this is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2872348/557906), I believe)? If so, does it follow from the well-known similar theorems from complex analysis? In the latter case (if $C$ does not enclose the origin) I guess one cannot replace $C$ with a homotopic path. Does it have anything to do with complex analysis residues? Is such integral always zero?

(Note that I'm not familiar with winding numbers.)

Comment: The curve cannot pass through $(0,0)$ since the integrand would be undefined there. Do you mean that the simple smooth closed curve bounds a region that contains $(0,0)$ or does not?

Comment: @Chickenmancer You are right, I've edited the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, if a curve is simple and positively oriented, then the winding number is $1.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number

Comment: The point [Nosrati's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2872330/11619) is that this differential form has $\arctan(y/x)$, that is, the polar angle coordinate $\phi=\phi(x,y)$, as *a potential*. So in any region of the plane  where $\phi$ is continuous (automatically also differentiable) the path integral only depends on the end points. So you just introduce a branch cut. That will cut a more general curve $C$ into finitely many piececs. You can move those pieces around homotopically (observing the branch cut) without changing the total line integral at all.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307738/application-of-greens-theorem-when-undefined-at-origin?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite $I$ as a contour integral. Let $z = x + i y$, then
$$I = \int_{\mathcal C} \frac {x dy - y dx} {x^2 + y^2} =
\int_a^b \frac {\operatorname{Im}(\overline z z')} {|z|^2} dt =
\operatorname{Im} \int_a^b \frac {z'} z dt =
\operatorname{Im} \int_{\mathcal C} \frac {dz} z.$$
This holds whether or not the curve is closed. The imaginary part of the logarithm is $\arg z$.

In vector terms, this is the two-dimensional version of Gauss's law. Let $\mathbf r = (x, y), \mathbf n = (y', -x')$. If the region $D$ enclosed by the curve does not contain the origin, then
$$I = \int_a^b \frac {\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf n} {r^2} dt =
\int_{\mathcal C} \frac {\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf n} {r^2 |\mathbf r'|} ds =
\int_{\mathcal C} \frac {\mathbf r \cdot \hat {\mathbf n}} {r^2} ds =
\iint_D \nabla \cdot \frac {\mathbf r} {r^2} dS = 0,$$
because $\nabla \cdot (\mathbf r / r^2) = 0$. Otherwise, if $\mathcal C_\epsilon$ is a small circle around the origin, the sum of $I$ and the integral over $\mathcal C_\epsilon$ with consistent orientations is zero by the same argument, and $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf n / r^2 = \epsilon^2/\epsilon^2$ on $\mathcal C_\epsilon$.